# Facing issue with sorting in EF Core & navigation property

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am working with .net core & EF core 2.0. 
I have the following 3 tables

1. User
2. Role
3. UserRoles

Now I want to display data on a screen where I have 2 column 
1. Username
2. Role

For allowing user sort, search & pagination I have following generic code with my application.

```
   public async Task<PagedResult<User>> GetAll(string filter, int pageIndex, int pageSize, string sortColumn, string sortDirection)
        {
            filter = filter?.Trim().ToLower();
            var data = usersRepository.Query(true).Include(x => x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(x => x.Role).AsQueryable();

            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
                {
                    data = data.Where(x => x.Username.ToLower().Contains(filter));
                }

                //sort 
                var ascending = sortDirection == "asc";
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortColumn))
                {
                    switch (sortColumn.Trim().ToLower())
                    {
                        case "username":
                            data = data.OrderBy(p => p.Username, ascending);
                            break;
                        case "isactive":
                            data = data.OrderBy(p => p.IsActive, ascending);
                            break;
                        case "role":
                            data = data.OrderBy(p => p.UserRoles.OrderBy(o => o.Role.Name), ascending);
                            break;
                        default:
                            data = data.OrderBy(p => p.Username, ascending);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                var test = data.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //todo:
            }
            return await data.GetPaged(pageIndex, pageSize);

        }
```

Where OrderBy is generic method

```
 public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, bool ascending)
        {
            return ascending ? source.OrderBy(keySelector) : source.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
        }
```

Now all works well except When I pass search column 'role'.

It gives me the following error.

**Exception**: *Failed to compare two elements in the array.*

**InnerException**: *At least one object must implement IComparable.*

How can I handle this scenario any help is appreciated.

Comment: User can have multiple roles. Do you want to repeat a username with different roles in your view or display a username and all its roles (e.g. divided by comma) in one row?

Comment: The user can have many roles, so it's unclear what do you mean by "sorting users by role".

Comment: User will have single role for now, but given provision for multiple at database level

Comment: Then "for now" you could use `OrderBy(p => p.UserRoles.Select(o => o.Role.Name).FirstOrDefault(), ascending)`. The exception in question is because `OrderBy` requires *single* value (cannot order by list of values).

Comment: @IvanStoev no luck with that as well, it gives "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Darn client evaluation :( Can you try the latest EF Core 2.2 or you are stuck with 2.0?

Comment: 2.2 has the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the middle layer to manage role name column. For this, I have created a new class called **"UserList"** with required properties in my response.

```
public async Task<PagedResult<UserList>> GetAll(string filter, int pageIndex, int pageSize, string sortColumn, string sortDirection)
        {
            filter = filter?.Trim().ToLower();
            var data = usersRepository.Query(true)
                .Include(x => x.UserRoles)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Role)
                .Select(x => new UserList()
                {
                    Username = x.Username,
                    UserId = x.UserId,
                    IsActive = x.IsActive,
                    RoleId = x.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId,
                    RoleName = x.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault().Role.Name
                })
                .AsQueryable();

            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
                {
                    data = data.Where(x => x.Username.ToLower().Contains(filter) || x.RoleName.ToLower().Contains(filter));
                }

                //sort 
                var ascending = sortDirection == "asc";
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortColumn))
                {
                    switch (sortColumn.Trim().ToLower())
                    {
                        case "username":
                            data = data.OrderBy(p => p.Username, ascending);
                            break;
                        case "isactive":
                            data = data.OrderBy(p => p.IsActive, ascending);
                            break;
                        case "rolename":
                            data = data.OrderBy(p => p.RoleName, ascending);
                            break;
                        default:
                            data = data.OrderBy(p => p.Username, ascending);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //todo:
            }

            return await data.GetPaged(pageIndex, pageSize);

    }
```